# Jquery.tinymce.js gets loaded but TinyMCE doesnt get inserted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

We have used tinyMCE at several places in our app just by adding a class to the text area or whichever element wherein we need to insert TinyMCE. But when I try to add tinyMCE to a newly created text area, it doesn't get loaded. But when I inspect the code, I Can find that the Jquery.tinymce.js script has been loaded. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you call the tinymce init function on pageload.
When you create a new textarea on the fly you should init that tinymce instance explicitly.
For this use:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'id_of_the_new_textarea');
```

Comment: I have already tried executing this command and it isn't working yet.

Comment: could you try loading the non-jquery build "tiny_mce.js" instead of the jquery build (which is a source of trouble)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it solved. Adding the command <%= tiny_mce_init %> did the trick.

Comment: ah, well - that's the ruby-way to initialize tinymce